# Run Java Mission Control as a daemon, and activate alerts?

Tags: monitoring, java, service

I would like to use Java Mission Control (JMC) to monitor a java application I have that will expose certain information via JMX.  In JMC it is possible to setup alerts to trigger when certain conditions are violated on certain JMX properties.

However in order for this to work you must manually start JMC, then connect to a JMX server, and then manually select the alerts you want to trigger as well.

Is there any way I can start JMC as a daemon, and have it activate my alerts automatically?